# Erro: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'. in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

> ERROR in src/app/new-applicant/new-applicant.service.ts(35,65): error
>   TS2345: Argument of type '{ reportProgress: boolean; observe: string;
>   headers: HttpHeaders; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{
>   headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; };
>   observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string |
>   string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json";
>   withCredentials?: boolean; }'.
>         Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
>           Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'.

```
    public generateHeaders()
    {
        let access=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("meta_info")).access
        // access=access.access;
        console.log(access)
        var headers_object = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer " + access);
        const httpOptions = {
            reportProgress:true,
            observe:'events',
            headers: headers_object
        };
        return httpOptions
    }
```

service

```
  public registerNewApplicant(data)
  {
    return this.http.post(environment.baseURL+"applicant/",data,this.jwtTokenGenerator.generateHeaders())
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `as const` to force TypeScript to infer the type of `observe` as the literal type `"events"` instead of `string`:

```js
observe: 'events' as const,
```

Each method in HttpClient has a bunch of overloads which expect `observe` to be one of the following: `"body"`, `"events"`, `"response"`.

TypeScript by default infers type of string literals as `string`, except in some contexts such as initializing a `const` or `readonly` fields. The return type of `generateHeaders` ends up being

```js
{ reportProgress: boolean; observe: string; headers: HttpHeaders; }
```

The info about `observe` being `"events"` is lost, so this value does not match any of the overloads.

Comment: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ArrayBuffer'. this error is showing.. how to observe the events

Answer (score 4):

Cast it to 'events'

```
observe: 'events' as 'events'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a typescript expert, but if you supply the `generateHeaders` method with a return type in the signature, it should fix your error.

```
public generateHeaders(): any {
  ...
}
```